# Dynamic DataTable and DataRow creation from class

Tags: c#, class, generics, methods, types

I have many classes of different sizes and types and I'm trying to get a generic script going to populate them.

Please consider the following code.  The problem I'm having is that at the end it only prints the column names (correct) but without the values.

Whilst stepping through the code I can see that it thinks the Type i'm passing in the createDataRow method is empty and I don't understand why.

```
public class tables { }
public class Dog : tables
{
    public string Breed { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int legs { get; set; }
    public bool tail { get; set; }
}



class Program
{
    public static DataTable CreateDataTable(Type animaltype)
    {
        DataTable return_Datatable = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in animaltype.GetProperties())
        {
            return_Datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, info.PropertyType));
        }
        return return_Datatable;
    }

    public static DataRow createDataRow(tables dog, DataTable touse) //This is half of the problem
    {
        Type type = dog.GetType();
        DataRow x = touse.NewRow();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(tables).GetProperties()) //this is the other half of the problem
        {
            x[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(dog, null);
        }

        return x;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dog Killer = new Dog();
        Killer.Breed = "Maltese Poodle";
        Killer.legs = 3;
        Killer.tail = false;
        Killer.Name = "Killer";

        DataTable dogTable = new DataTable();
        dogTable = CreateDataTable(typeof(Dog));
        DataRow dogRow = dogTable.NewRow();
        dogRow = createDataRow(Killer, dogTable); //This is where I pass the data
        dogTable.Rows.Add(dogRow);

        foreach (DataRow row in dogTable.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in dogTable.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Column {0} =" + row[col].ToString(),col.ColumnName);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }      
}
```

Now if I was to change the following:

```
 public static DataRow createDataRow(tables dog, DataTable touse)
```

to

```
 public static DataRow createDataRow(Dog dog, DataTable touse)
```

and

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(tables).GetProperties())
```

to

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(Dog).GetProperties())
```

...everything works fine.
But I don't want to do this as it means I'll have to create a "createDataRow" function for each of my classes of which I have hundreds.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need this function?

```
public static DataRow createDataRow(Dog dog, DataTable touse)
```

Dog is derived from tables, so you can use this:

```
public static DataRow createDataRow(tables dog, DataTable touse)
```

If you have different implementation, you can override the base method, but in this case you have to make it virtual (and declare base method in the base class):

```
public virtual DataRow createDataRow(DataTable touse)
```

and don't make it static, if you want to enjoy the polymorphism benefits.

You don't have to pass the tables instance, just call on the instance:

```
tables foo = new Dog();
var dr = foo.createDataRow(return_Datatable);
```

classes:

```
public class tables 
{ 
    public virtual DataRow createDataRow(DataTable touse)
    {
       //base implementation
    }

}

public class Dog : tables
{
    public string Breed { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int legs { get; set; }
    public bool tail { get; set; }
    public override DataRow createDataRow(DataTable touse)
    {
       //derived implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @speti43, however I think I'm having a problem with the "tables foo = new Dog()" statement.  When I do that, it doesn't recognise any of the Dog properties in the main block code.

Comment: Of course, because you haven't declared the properties in the base class. Thus it's a base class type inside a derived class instance, It doesn't know about the derived class properties. So you have to declare the properties in the base class, if you want to use it in all derived classes. The base class is the "contract" for properties and methods. If you put something to base class, you can be sure, it will be inside all derived classes as well. Maybe with different implementation, but it doesn't matter

Comment: ah yes! obvious, sorry about that.  However this leads me to a problem.  Like I said I have hundreds (well 143) classes.  And the properties in each class is different.  maybe I should try and reverse the two or something

Comment: If your code is redundant, there could be a problem, but if you have totally different class members, you can't optimize it with inheritance.

Comment: Ok, time for a rethink.  Thanks for your help.  I'll accept your answer because it works even though my solution is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

I got it licked!

So the trick was in the CreateDataRow method to pass the class as an object.

```
namespace Generics
```

{

```
public class Dog
{
    public string Breed { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int legs { get; set; }
    public bool tail { get; set; }   

}

public class Cat
{
    public string Breed { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int toes { get; set; }
    public bool Aggressive { get; set; }
    public bool tail { get; set; }
}



class Program
{


    public static DataTable CreateDataTable(Type animaltype)
    {

        DataTable return_Datatable = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in animaltype.GetProperties())
        {
            return_Datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, info.PropertyType));
        }
        return return_Datatable;
    }


    public static DataRow makeRow(object input, DataTable table)
    {
        Type inputtype = input.GetType();
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in inputtype.GetProperties())
        {
            row[info.Name] = info.GetValue(input, null);
        }
        return row;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Cat Dexter = new Cat();
        Dexter.Breed = "Bengal";
        Dexter.toes = 12;
        Dexter.tail = false;
        Dexter.Name = "Killer";
        Dexter.Aggressive = true;

        Dog Killer = new Dog();            
        Killer.Breed = "Maltese Poodle";
        Killer.legs = 3;
        Killer.tail = false;
        Killer.Name = "Killer";       

        DataTable dogTable = CreateDataTable(typeof(Dog));
        dogTable.Rows.Add(makeRow(Killer, dogTable));

        DataTable catTable = CreateDataTable(typeof(Cat));
        catTable.Rows.Add(makeRow(Dexter, catTable));


        foreach (DataRow rows in catTable.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in catTable.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Column {0} =" + rows[col].ToString(), col.ColumnName.PadRight(15));
            }
        }


        foreach (DataRow rows in dogTable.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in dogTable.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Column {0} =" + rows[col].ToString(),col.ColumnName.PadRight(15));
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }      
}
```

Comment: @speti43, So I pass into makerow the class as an object, then get the type.  From that I can take the properties.